# If $\alpha\wedge d\alpha$ is a volume form, there exists a vector field $X$ such that $i_X\alpha\equiv1$ and $i_X (d\alpha)\equiv0$.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, vector-fields

I'm currently stuck on the following problem:

> Let $\alpha$ be a 1-form on a connected 3-manifold $M$ such that $\alpha\wedge d\alpha$ is a volume form. Show that there exists a vector field $X$ on $M$ such that $i_X\alpha\equiv1$ and $i_X(d\alpha)\equiv0$.

I believe there are a few routes to solve this problem, but I keep getting stuck at each step. Working locally, I first wrote $$\alpha=\alpha_1dx+\alpha_2dy+\alpha_3dz$$ and noticed that $\alpha$ is non-vanishing. Indeed, if not, there exists a point $p\in M$ such that $\alpha_i(p)=0$ for $i=1,2,3$. Computing $\omega=\alpha\wedge d\alpha$, it follows that $\omega_p=0$, a contradiction. Thus, because $\alpha\neq0$, we get (by a theorem about $\alpha\wedge d\alpha$) that $\ker\alpha$ is *not* involutive, but I'm really not sure what I can do from here. I suppose that if we choose appropriate vector fields $X,Y\in\ker\alpha$, we do get that

$$d \alpha(X, Y)=X(\alpha(Y))-Y(\alpha(X))-\alpha([X, Y])=-\alpha([X,Y])$$

is non-zero.

Alternatively, there is the usual expansion

$$i_X(\alpha\wedge d\alpha)=i_X\alpha\wedge d\alpha-\alpha\wedge i_Xd\alpha,$$
which connects both the conditions that $i_X\alpha\equiv1$ and $i_Xd\alpha\equiv0$ with the contraction of a volume form, but again I'm not able see where this leads me.

I'd really appreciate any help towards a full solution. I'm reviewing my knowledge of smooth manifold theory, so this problem is not homework (although it's from an old exam at my university). Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered looking at the Cartan formula for $\mathscr L_X\alpha$?

Comment: Yes, the Cartan formula gives $$\mathscr{L}_X\alpha=di_X\alpha+i_Xd\alpha,$$ which, to satisfy the conditions of the problem statement, must vanish. However, I'm not sure how to determine $X$ from this information.

Comment: Locally: there is a unique 3-vector $I$ such that $$i_I(\alpha\wedge d\alpha) = \langle\alpha\wedge d\alpha, I\rangle = 1$$ and since $i_X(\alpha\wedge d\alpha) = d\alpha$ we must have $$i_{d\alpha}(I) = i_{i_X(\alpha\wedge d\alpha)}(I) = X\langle\alpha\wedge d\alpha, I\rangle = X. $$ This probably extends globally really easily, but I'm only familiar with exterior algebra and not so much differential geometry.

Comment: Locally, this follows easily from the Darboux normal form for a contact structure, but I still don’t see a global argument. Please tell us what precise topics are covered by this exam.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thank you for your comment. This question is from a final exam from my university's first-year graduate course on smooth manifolds (following Lee's book). As far as I'm aware, this course didn't cover symplectic/contact geometry, but culminated in Chapter 20 of Lee's textbook.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don’t know Lee’s book or its theorems and exercises. I would expect him to prove Darboux’s Theorem and Moser’s trick.

Comment: This is very helpful — I'll play around with the problem using Darboux's theorem. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're not already aware, the vector field $X$ is called the *Reeb vector field* associated to $\alpha$.

The key piece of the construction is [Jacobi's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Determinant), which states that the determinant of an odd-dimensional skew-symmetric matrix is zero. This implies that a skew 2-form such as $d\alpha$ has nonzero kernel when viewed as a map $T_pM\to T^*_pM$ given by $v\to\iota_vd\alpha$.

Since $\alpha\wedge d\alpha$ is a volume form, we must have that $\ker\alpha\cap\ker d\alpha=0$, and thus $\ker d\alpha$ is one dimensional and $\alpha|_{\ker d\alpha}$ is nonvanishing. The Reeb field $X$ is exactly the preimage of $\{1\}$ under $\alpha|_{\ker d\alpha}$